# How to annotate string on resulted Image of each page of PDF document using ImageMagick.convert command

Tags: java, pdf, imagemagick

We are using the below command to convert the multi pages of PDF document to the JPEG file by annotating the string, in the ImageMagick-6.9.4-Q16 version.

```
imconvert "{Source-Path}\OpenTextMediaManagement105-Installation-Guide.pdf" 
-quality 25 -pointsize 20  -fill "#FFFFFF" -gravity center -annotate 40x40+0+0 "EA CONFIDENTIAL-INTERNAL ONLY" 
"{Destination-Path}\OpenTextMediaManagement105-Installation-Guidepdf-%03d.jpg"
```

But in the output JPEG files, could see shadow effect around the annotated string, as shown in the ImageMagick-6.9.4-Q16 image and also letters inside image were blurred.

[ImageMagick-6.9.4-Q16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4QZY.jpg)

And when we used the below command in the ImageMagick-6.4.6-Q16 version getting the output as shown in the ImageMagick-6.4.6-Q16.jpg file.

```
imconvert "{Source-Path}\OpenTextMediaManagement105-Installation-Guide.pdf" 
-resample 100 -quality 25 -pointsize 20  -fill rgba(0,0,0,0.4)  -gravity center -annotate 40x40+0+0 "EA CONFIDENTIAL-INTERNAL ONLY"
"{Destination-Path}\OpenTextMediaManagement105-Installation-Guidepdf-%03d.jpg"
```

[ImageMagick-6.4.6-Q16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOwv2.jpg)

So could you please help me on, how do we get the same output like clarity, Annotate string-- as shown in ImageMagick-6.4.6-Q16.jpg,  by using the ImageMagick-6.9.4-Q16 version?